# Java 8 : String join operation has significant performance impact

Tags: java, java-8

I was going through the newly added existing features introduced in Java-8. 
One simple feature newly added to String class is quiet appealing for me – that is [String Join method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-).

Example:

```
String.join(" ", "AZY","BAX"); // returns AZY BAX
```

For curiosity, I have checked the performance (execution time) of this feature by writing a simple java code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    String abc= String.join(" ,"AZY","BAX" … // joining 1000 words of size 3 char;
    long diff = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println(" Java 8 String Join " + diff);

     start = System.nanoTime();
    abc= "AZY"+"BAX"+"CBA"+ … // adding 1000 word of size 3 char;
    diff = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println(" Tranditional " + diff);

    start = System.nanoTime();
    new StringBuilder().append("AZY").append("BAX").appe… // appending 1000 word of size 3 char;
    diff = System.nanoTime() - start;
    System.out.println(" String Builder Append " + diff);

}
```

The result is not so exciting for me (time in neno sec)

```
Java 8 String Join     1340114
Tranditional             59785
String Builder Append   102807
```

The complexity is of o(n) – in-fact it is (n * Size of individual element length)

Other performance measures (memory etc) I have not measured.

My questions are:

1. Is there anything wrong in my measurement (most of the time I believe on the jdk guys)
2. What is the intent of adding “join” API to String class
3. Is there any performance analysis for Java 8 is available

Comment: Writing a correct benchmark in Java is not so simple because of JIT heuristics and garbage collection. See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would one use this method instead of `+`?

Comment: Also, concatenating string literals is done at compile time, so you're not really testing anything in the second test.

Comment: @Djon because `+` is the [slowest operation known to man](http://kaioa.com/node/59). If you want to know more read [this excellent Joel on software article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).

Comment: Thanks Jesper.. Kishan.. Its my copy/paste miste...

It should be

String abc= String.join(" ","AZY" ...

Comment: the code isn't even equivalent, the join has the delimiter while the traditional and stringbuilder don't.

Comment: @BoristheSpider look again there are [2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) [join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) methods BOTH use the delimiter. one is just a vararg in which you can also pass an array

Comment: @ratchetfreak you're right - I just assumed the varags method was `first, rest...` rather than `delim, data...`. Good spot!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

First things first. **This is not how you microbench Java**

Read [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) first. Your numbers are completely irrelevant, so lets ignore them.

Looking at the second example:

```
abc= "AZY"+"BAX"+"CBA"+...
```

These look like compile time constants to me. This `String` would be concatenated at compile time and there would be nothing to benchmark. This is a useless comparison as the whole point of the `StringBuilder` or `String.join` is to concatenate `String`s that are not compile time constant.

Moving onto comparing the `StringBuilder` and `String.join`. Looking at the source code:

```
public static String join(CharSequence delimiter, CharSequence... elements) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(delimiter);
    Objects.requireNonNull(elements);
    // Number of elements not likely worth Arrays.stream overhead.
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);
    for (CharSequence cs: elements) {
        joiner.add(cs);
    }
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

This uses a `StringJoiner`. A `StringJoiner` simply uses a `StringBuilder` under the hood, so the two are equivalent.

It is often much more informative to look *at the code* than to try and benchmark performance. Even if you do benchmark correctly.

It's also worth noting that your first method, with `join`, joins the 1000 `String`s on " " (space). Whereas your `StringBuilder` method simply appends them together. These two are not the same.

The point of the `String.join` method is that you can do:

```
String.join(", ", "a", "b", "c") // result is "a, b, c"
```

With a `StringBuilder` you would have to add a lot more code.

Comment: This question it not trying to benchmark Java. but to understand the intent of "join" API. (I think its clear from the questions). I am not still sure why we need an API that does nested looping (one in String.jave- join() method as you said which internally invoke append() method of AbstractStringBuilder) instead of using StringBuilder directly

Comment: @dipankaj because the whole point of Java 8 is to add methods that avoid explicit looping and use more functional paradigms. `String.join` is supposed to be a shortcut for `Stream.of(a, b, c).collect(Collectors.joining())`. If you don't see the benefits of allowing users to join a `String` in one line of code rather than 4 then just don't use it...

Comment: Unless this is documented, expected behavior, this would be JVM dependent.  Which JVM did you pull this from?  I was somewhat expecting it to sum the length of the strings in the array and just create the destination array.  Especially as using a builder like that is likely to allocate arrays multiple times if you're dealing with the number of strings the OP is dealing with...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, of course it's JVM dependant - this is Oracle's. The implementation would be the same for OpenJDK I suppose. The algorithm just reuses the `StringJoiner` from the joining `Collector` of the `Stream` API. If you really need to squeeze out more performance then you could do what you say.

Comment: There’s another difference. `String.join` is a *varargs* method which implies before it even starts its work, a temporary array is created and filled with all 1000 `String` references while the `StringBuilder` equivalent in the question just calls `append` 1000 times.

Comment: How do we understand the impact on memory efficiency when using StringJoiner vs StringBuilder? Is there any impact?

Comment: I don't understand your question @RomanG. As I said a `StringJoiner` uses a `StringBuilder` to do the work.

Comment: Understood. Thank you.