# Java code indentation

Tags: java, tabs, indentation

For 'case 1' below, the console prints the text as intended.

case 1:
        System.out.println ("Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text "); break;

However, I want to format the code so that, when reading the code, the second line of text is aligned with the first: so that the S in 'System' is aligned with the T of the 'Text' that is at the start of the second line of text. If I use the tab to indent the second line, the tab appears in the text that is printed to the console. Is there a way around this?

Comment: You have a literal string which cannot be formatted.  As @MuhammetAliAsan alluded to, you would have to break up the literal string and then your IDE (e.g. eclipse) will do the proper formatting for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has a "+" operator for strings which will concat multiple strings together.
However, String concat using "+" is known to cause [performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053499/java-8-string-join-operation-has-significant-performance-impact). Hence, it is better to save the entire string as a single string instead of splitting for readability.

```
case 1:
      System.out.println ("Text Text Text Text" +
                         " Text Text Text Text" +
                         " Text Text Text Text Text ");
      break;
```

If you are very particular, then you can consider a Stringbuffer or stringbuilder which has better performance than "+".

Using stringbuffer, you can do something like,

```
case 1:
      System.out.println ( new StringBuffer
                                 (" Text Text Text Text")  
                         .append (" Text Text Text Text")  
                         .append (" Text Text Text Text")  );
      break;
```

Answer (score 1):

A stupid workaround:

```
  System.out.println("Text text text " +
  "text text text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use Concatination (+) of Java String. [See Example](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/combine-two-strings)

```
case 1: System.out.println ("Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text" +
        " Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text "); break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply split the output string into multiple parts with the "+" operand like so

You need to add more quotations before and after the +: " " + " " + " " you can do this for as long 
as you like, this is also how you easily put variables inside an output string

```
System.out.println("Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text" +
"Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text"); break;

System.out.println("something " + variable1 + " something else " + variable2);
```