# Avoid an operation on the first and/or last element

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list with some text:

```
my_list = ['sentence1','sentence2','sentence3','sentence4' ]
```

And I want as output a string like this:

```
'sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4'
```

If I make this, I get an aditional  `', '` at the end

```
string_sentences = ''
for sentence in my_list:
    string_sentences +=  sentence +', '
string_sentences

output: 'sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4, '
```

same with this approach, but now at the beginning:

```
string_sentences = ''
for sentence in my_list:
    string_sentences += ', ' + sentence 
string_sentences

', sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4'
```

Only thing I can think to solve it is to keep track of the indices

```
string_sentences = ''
for i,sentence in enumerate(my_list):
    if i +1 < len(my_list):
        string_sentences += sentence +', '
    else:
        string_sentences += sentence
string_sentences

ouput: 'sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4'
```

But this seems like a very common issues, and I wonder whether is a more pythonic way to solve it.

Comment: Your suggested way is the only way to do this nicely in many languages (apart from having a boolean variable `firstTime` which is set to `False` after the first loop), apparently. In Python, you have `join` method as suggested in the answer.

Comment: @justhalf actually join is a common way to do this in [Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24053499/java-8-string-join-operation-has-significant-performance-impact), [Perl](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html), and [C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078/most-effecient-way-to-concatenate-strings) (though stringbuilder may be used for larger values) as well

Comment: I was not aware that they have `join` methods in Perl and C#, but at least in Java, it was a features quite late to be added (Java 8 is still considered new for me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to convert your list to a string. Provide a separator that will go between each element that is extracted from the list that goes in to your string. In this case `,` and a space ' ' after the comma:

```
my_list = ['sentence1','sentence2','sentence3','sentence4' ]
s = ', '.join(my_list)
```

By printing s we will have:

```
'sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4'
```

Just some extra notes about why using `join` here would actually be preferable, is because it actually runs at C speed as opposed to the speed you get from a Python loop. Read about performance tips [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips).

Finally, a warning when doing this. The `join` always expects an iterable of strings. Which means, if you have a list of integers `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You will not be able to call `join` directly on this. You would have to cast each of those values to an `str`. A simple example would be something like this:

```
list_of_ints = [1, 2, 3, 4]
', '.join([str(n) for n in list_of_ints])
```

So, to further explain what just happened in the above example. Since we actually have a list of integers. In order to successfully create our string from that list, we need to cast each element in the list to a string. In order to do this, we will use a list-comprehension to create this list of string integers, and then call your join method.

Now, the reason why we are actually not using a generator expression here and using a list comprehension, is because in fact the join method will actually scan the iterable twice, therefore the comprehension in this case is actually faster.

This is actually very nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024).

Comment: Thanks, about the 'join(str(n) for n in list_of_ints)' what is getting the join mehod from 'str(n) for n in list_of_ints'? why isn't needed  to put it as a list comprehension or a generator join([str(n) for n in list_of_ints])?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez I'm glad you asked that question. I am updating my answer to give you exactly that answer.

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> my_list = ['sentence1','sentence2','sentence3','sentence4' ]
>>> ', '.join(my_list)
'sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4'
>>> 
>>> result = ', '.join(my_list)
>>> result
'sentence1, sentence2, sentence3, sentence4'
>>>
```

Comment: Don't use answers to ask a question: be more assertive!

Comment: I strongly suggest that you modify that wording: some users (especially those that spend a lot of time in the review queues) will downvote or flag answers that start with a clarification question.